# How to Integrate path social network in android?

Tags: android, path

How to integrate path in  android Application and how to give OAuth2 Redirect URL.
I am getting issue in come back to my application after successful authentication while Re-Direct Path API on browser for authentication.
please response as soon as possible,I will be thankful for this.

https://path.com/developers/docs#status

This is my Authentication code

```
 btn_share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {

           Log.i("MainActivity", "onCreate called");

           Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://partner.path.com/oauth2/authenticate?response_type=code&client_id=e1438845936c1e9dae8d3e0a5739028a73768fa9");

           Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uri);

           startActivityForResult(intent,101);

           Log.i("MainActivity","startActivityForResult called");      

       }
   });
}
```

How to share post on "Path Social Network" please give me proper code

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: thank you , I want to integrate Path Social Network in my android Application and I read this doc https://path.com/developers/docs#status but I am not understand how to integrate .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope you have registered your application and gave the **redirectUri** to which you want to be redirected after the successful login.

Declare this `intent-filter` in your manifest with your corresponding activity :

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="t4jsample"
                android:scheme="oauth" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Make sure your **redirectUri** and the scheme + host . i.e `oauth://t4jsample` both matches.

Comment: thank you so much , you save my time .

Comment: @user5829709 You can upvote and accept my answer if it helped you :)

Comment: please give me one more answer , how to integrate Path Social Network in android Application and share post in Path.